# React not re-rendering on state change with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-hooks, virtual-dom

I'm trying to create a quiz making app where the user can add multiple questions to a dynamic form. Within this form there are question components which the user can add or remove as they desire. When the user clicks the new question handler (handleNewQuestion) a new question is concatenated onto the questions array in the component state.

```
const handleNewQuestion = () => {
      setQuestions([
         ...questions,
         <Question
            key={questions.length}
            count={questions.length}
            formData={formData}
            setFormData={setFormData}
            handleRemoveQuestion={handleRemoveQuestion}
         />
      ])
   }

<Button onClick={handleNewQuestion} variant="outline-primary">
    New Question
</Button>
```

The problem I'm having is that whenever I attempt to remove a question with the remove question handler (handleRemoveQuestion) it always removes the wrong question. When trying to solve this I console logged the questions array in state and found that the new questions weren't in the array, also I get different results depending on which question component I click on. You can see the results I'm getting in the image provided.

[quiz form with 2 questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmfvL.png)

Essentially whats happening is that depending on which question component I try to remove the console shows the questions array at different states. For example when I try to remove the first question component I get an empty array and when I click the second question component I get an array with one element. Even if multiple questions are rendered, if I try to remove the first question I still get an empty array.

I have no idea why this is happening and I would really appreciate it if someone could explain whats going on here.

cheers!

Comment: That call to `setQuestions` should definitely trigger a re-render. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: "whenever I attempt to remove a question with the remove question handler (handleRemoveQuestion) it always removes the wrong question" - you're only showing adding new questions but not showing the code you're having issues with.

Comment: The remove question handler is currently only logging the questions array, I didn't think it was necessary to include that. Sorry I should have been more specific.

Comment: The image linked doesn't really inform much. `handleRemoveQuestion` would seem to be using some logic that needs fixing since it logs different things for different questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use that `key` if you're modifying the array (in any way other than just adding to it). From [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance **and may cause issues with component state**. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an [in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

*(my emphasis)*

Also, note that nothing in your call to `setQuestions` is going to update the `count` on existing questions, which seems like a problem.

Assign your questions unique IDs, and use those IDs when removing questions. If questions don't intrinsically have a unique ID, one way you can give them one is to use a variable outside the component that gives the "next" ID to use:

```
let nextQuestionId = 1;

const YourComponent = props => {
    // ...
    const handleNewQuestion = () => {
      setQuestions([
         ...questions,
         <Question
            key={nextQuestionId++}
            count={questions.length}
            formData={formData}
            setFormData={setFormData}
            handleRemoveQuestion={handleRemoveQuestion}
         />
      ]);
   };

   const removeQuestion = id => {
       setQuestions(questions.filter(q => q.id !== id));
   };
};
```

That example doesn't deal with the `count` problem. If questions really need to have the count, you'll have to re-create **all** questions when adding/removing. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader in hopes that you don't really need `count` on `Question` anyway...